# TeXstudio shows colored slide with video file

Tags: texstudio, video

My configuration is Ubuntu 16.04 (TeXstudio 2.10.8 ). I have a frame with a video (using multimedia package). I can see the video with Okular. The only problem is with the internal viewer of TeXstudio that hides all the slide with a color (even if the size of the movie is small).[image]

The code is

```
    \begin{frame}{Real-time Tests}
    Experiments bla bla bla

     \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

            bla bla bla

        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{textblock*}{1\textwidth}(0.5cm,-1.5cm)
                \movie[width=.75\textwidth, showcontrols=true]
                {\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{play.png}}{video/video.mp4}
            \end{textblock*}
        \end{column}
     \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

So, I have no problem with the presentation itself (I can see the video), the only problem is that I would like to remove this big colored thing during the editing. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, that's probably a viewer/rendering problem you can't solve with TeX.

Comment: you could try to upgrade  TeXstudio to the latest version to see if it makes any difference and if it doesn't just comment out the `\movie` code while you need to edit the slides.

Comment: As far as I know, the video option for the internal pdf viewer is not default. If you want to enable this experimental option, you have to compile your own texstudio from source - during compilation you will be asked if you want to enable it.

Comment: As far as I know, the video option for the internal pdf viewer is not default. If you want to enable this experimental option, you have to compile your own texstudio from source - during compilation you will be asked if you want to enable it.